# Composite C1 - Multiple sites/domains, same design, different main navigation / footer

Tags: c1-cms

I have a Composite C1 site with 5 different sites in it (with 5 different domains).

Each site has multiple languages.

Each site has the same basic design (html/css/images) - though is about a slightly different topic with different content.

What is the best way to insert a different navigation menu at the top of each website, and footer at the bottom of each, whilst keeping other layout items the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menus like Composite.Navigation.Distributed or Layout.Navigation.Menu (from the starter site) are subsite-aware etc.

If your subsites share the same layout, you can simply insert the menus like the ones above, they will correctly show the pages that belong to the current website (subsite). you don't need to explicitly "tell" the menu to show pages from a specific site.

Comment: thx. Is there any way to hide some items from any of these menus? What is best menu?

Comment: For example - I have a 'footer' section, and another I don't want in the main nav - and the front page has a long title that's used as the nav link.

Comment: I also need to precisely control the HTML that the navigation outputs (embed it in a styled <ul>) - is that possible also? thx

Comment: are you referring to Composite.Navigation.Distributed.XSLT? (<that's all I can find in Packages)

Comment: > are you referring to Composite.Navigation.Distributed.XSLT
1. If you've installed the Open Cph Razor starter site, you should have the Composite.Navigation.Distributed.Razor already installed. No need to install the XSLT version. 2. You can find the Razor version of the function that comes with the package under Functions/ Razor Functions/Composite/Navigation

Comment: > Is there any way to hide some items from any of these menus? Answer: The Composite.Navigation.Distributed function that outputs a menu has a few parameters. You can experiment with them to see if you can achieve your goal. If not, you can edit the function and customize it so it serves up to your needs.

Comment: > I also need to precisely control the HTML that the navigation outputs (embed it in a styled <ul>) - is that possible also? Answer: Simply edit and customize the function that outputs the menu (Functions/ Razor Functions/Composite/Navigation/Distributed). Or even create your own function for these purposes reusing some of the code from the Distributed function that works for you.

Comment: > What is best menu? Answer: You can read about your naviagtion menu options at http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market?category=Navigation